# Folder Access restriction in Shared Hosting

Tags: php, shared-hosting, restrictions

In a shared hosting I use (where I don't have access to httpd.conf files) I want PHP files in "MyTargetFolder" to not have ability to access anything in upper directories.

It needs some configuration like **OPEN_BASEDIR, SAFE_MODE, passthru,readfile,exec,system,shell_exec,escapeshellarg,escapeshellcmd,proc_close**...

But [**here**](http://codesphpjs.blogspot.com/2015/05/restrict-php-access-upper-directory.html) I have found OPEN_BASEDIR is said to be not a good solution. Also, SAFE_MODE is deprecated.  What can be a solution?

Note: question  was for "shared" hosting, not VPS or above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you are not trying to be a shared hosting provider, but you are using shared hosting, and want to restrict access for files inside one specific folder.

In that case, `open_basedir` would do exactly what you want.

If you are allowed to use `.htaccess` files, just create one in `MyTargetFolder` and put this line in it:

```
php_value open_basedir /var/www/
```

If you are not allowed to use `.htaccess` files, you would need to set the setting in every one of your PHP files inside `MyTargetFolder`:

```
ini_set("open_basedir", "/var/www/");
```

If you now have a PHP file in the folder with eg this line:

```
echo file_get_contents($_GET['x']);
```

A call to:

```
?x=../../../../../../etc/passwd
```

Would result in:

```
 Warning: file_get_contents(): open_basedir restriction in effect. File(../../../../../../etc/passwd) is not within the allowed path(s)
```

Please do note that remote files can still be accessed, eg:

```
?x=http://localhost/shell.php
```

Comment: a main downside of this is that that .htaccess can be modified itself it site is hacked, and attacker just deletes that  file and can access anything. So, i conclude in Shared Hosting it's not available to have it, unless there is some settings in the hosting panel level.